# VueRouter - protegiendo ruta con valores guardados en el store de mi Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

estoy intentando proteger la ruta `/profile` de forma que solo puedan entrar usuarios logeados, mi criterio para ello es que en vuex, la variable token no este a null.

Mi vuex contiene lo siguiente:

**state**

```
     state:{
            user:{
                name:null,
                token:null
            }
    
    },
  getters:{
        getToken(state){
            return state.user.token;
        }
    },
```

Mis rutas son las siguientes:

```
const routes = [
    {path: '', component:Home},
    {path: '/register', component:RegisterForm},
    {path: '/profile', component:Profile,meta:{auth:true}},
    {path: '*', component:RegisterForm},
];
```

De las cuales, la ruta `/profile` necesita cumplir el meta indicado en la misma.
Este meta se resuelve de la siguiente manera:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.auth)) {
      // this route requires auth, check if logged in
      // if not, redirect to login page.
      if (store.getters.getToken) {
        next();

       } else {
         next({path: '/register'})
      }
    } else {
      next() // make sure to always call next()!
    }
  })
```

Basicamente ese guard va a mirar que exista ya un token almacenado. Como estoy haciendo pruebas he metido a mano el token con la extension de vuejs para firefox:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como en un principio comprueba que no sea null, ya deberia dejarme ir a `/profile`. Pero no es asi.
Si os fijais en la imagen, a la funcion que estoy llamando `getToken` si contiene un valor, el del data, por tanto no es null. No veo porque no pasa por ahi.

PD: el objeto store usado en el middleware de la ruta esta anteriormente importado en el fichero y sin ningun error. De hecho lo esta leyendo.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías ejecutar el getter al momento de realizar la consulta de la existencia del token:  if (store.getters.**getToken()**)